# JAR won't work after adding images

Tags: java, jar, png, jcomponent

I've written a game that uses PNGs, and when I exported it, the images wouldn't work. I added `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` to everywhere I import an image, but the JAR won't even launch anymore. It used to open, but none of the images worked. Now it won't even open the JAR.

This is how I get the image for the muffin: 
`muffin=new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("muffin.png")).getImage();`
Actual path for it is: `C:\Users\My User Name\Dropbox\FinalProjectWithoutApplet\muffin.png`

What should I do to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the images contained in your jar file? Extract it and check this please.

Comment: Yes, they are. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/xNmUhYi)

Comment: How are you using the `getResource()` method? post all the relevant code please

Comment: Run your jar from the command line to see if there are Exceptions thrown.

Comment: @BackSlash, I have a character that has a setRightImage and setLeftImage method: `setRightImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Knight_RIGHT.png")).getImage());`

Comment: You've got a *lot* of stuff in that jar file that really shouldn't be there. Java backup files (*.java~) and heck, the source code to start with. It looks like you've also got a lot of source control conflicts on *class* files, which is a bit worrying.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I've been using Dropbox for the project, and the person I made the project with occasionally was on at the same time. I assure you the project works just fine in the IDE (I use BlueJ).

Comment: @faeophyta: Yes, it's not that it would cause a problem - but it's a big mess which you should clear up anyway. You should be sharing *source* files rather than *class* files... and you'd be much better off using a proper source control system.

Comment: @user714965, I ran it from command line, and I got: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source) at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:134) at mainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:14)`  Imgur link: [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/cfGNthz)

Comment: Ok, NPE means that you fail to get image from resource. This means that either your image does not exist or not there or your path is wrong. Please send a code fragment where you retrieve this image. Do it in continuation of your question: it is hard to read code from comment.

Comment: Is line 14 the one with `muffin.png`? (It looks like you've got a lot of resources.) You should definitely look at line 14 first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Turns out my cases mismatched. The IDE didn't care that one was called `"muffin.png"` in code vs. `"Muffin.png"`. Another case I found was `"DoubleJumpIcon.png"` vs. `"DoubleJumpIcon.PNG"`. Every single case matters it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("muffin.png")` is looking for the image `muffin.png` *in the same directory where your class is*.

I means that if your class's name is `com.mycompany.game.MyClass` the image is expected to be in `com/mycompany/game/muffin.png`. If this is not the location write absolute path that starts with `/`, for example `/img/muffin.png`.

And in future if program does not work start from examining the stack trace.

Comment: The image is in the directory with the source files, do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: No, the use of `getClassLoader()` means it will look from the *root* directory. If it were just `Class.getResource` this would be true.

Comment: The images should be in classpath, i.e. where class files are. Source should not be in jar file at all.